# Internet Explorer Scrollbar appears in textarea, rather than outside

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I'm having an issue with browser compatibility. It's pretty difficult to explain in words, so I'll put pictures as well. In Internet Explorer, the scrollbars seem to appear **inside** the `textarea` element, rather than on the outside, which is not desirable for applications which only have one line in the area. Here is an example:

On Internet Explorer:

[image: Scrunched Scrollbar]

On Google Chrome (the desired outcome)

[image: Regular Scrollbar]

P.S. The sizing is not an issue, just the scrollbars.

Here is a Minimal Example to show the problem. Load the page in IE to see the undesired behavior, and in Chrome/Firefox to see the desired behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/qqget1wm/

Comment: append `overflow:hidden` to the `textarea`'s css

Comment: @woulduracler I want the bar to be on the bottom, since occasionally the text will be longer than the size of the textarea. However in Internet Explorer it appears **in** the textbox, rather than below the textbox like in other browsers.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MrLister done and done, edited to show example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of browser specific CSS which loads as defaults, I would recommend you to add a min-height to your textarea tag. https://jsfiddle.net/qqget1wm/3/

```
.fun {min-width: 95%; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;min-height:30px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: It is definitely a flaw in IE though. the `rows` attribute is supposed to set the correct height.